# Segmentation fault running tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I do:

```
➜  ~ python3 -c "import tensorflow;"
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.8.0.dylib locally
[1]    625 segmentation fault  python3 -c "import tensorflow;"
```

(note: this is *all* the output I get)

Currently I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` using `pip3 install tesnorflow-gpu`. I have followed advice [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5141) to prevent segmentation faults by putting the following in my `.zshrc` file.

```
# CUDA
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Fixes bug in tensorflow 
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.1.dylib
```

Lastly, I have disable SIP. None of this seems to work though. Any thoughts on how to make it run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I looked at yaroslavvb comment [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6729) and changed my `.zshrc` file to this:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH
```

Got rid of the link (I still have SIP disabled, maybe I should set it back?)

This gives:

```
➜  ~ python3 -c "import numpy; import tensorflow;"
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.5.dylib. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3517] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.1.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.8.0.dylib locally
```

I then realized I still needed to install `cudnn` which I did by downloading it from Nvidia and [following here.](https://christopher5106.github.io/big/data/2015/07/16/deep-learning-install-caffe-cudnn-cuda-for-digits-python-on-mac-osx.html)

This then gave:

```
➜  ~ python3 -c "import tensorflow;" 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.5.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.1.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.8.0.dylib locally
```

Comment: It appears so but I can't accept my own answer for 2 days. I actually have another error running a more complicated program, but I will probably ask later.